# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'voice_clientn'

Tags: python, discord.py

I built a music bot but I have made a mistake.

The error I get is exactly like this; HELP ME PLEASE

Commands

````
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_clientn(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    players[server.id] = player 
    player.start()```
````

Comment: Can you post  an error?

Answer (score 0):

The `Guild` object doesn't have `voice_clientn` it is `voice_client`

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    players[server.id] = player 
    player.start()
```